# How to open different collapse buttons in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

For an application, I need several collapse buttons. I am using React-Bootstrap for that.

But when I click one of the buttons, all buttons open. I tried to change their id but it did not work. What I want is only the button I click will open.

```
function ... {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
...
return(
...
```

**This is button 1**

```
<Button
                                        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                                        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
                                        aria-expanded={open}
                                    >
                                        Satış Artışı
                                    </Button>
                                    <Collapse in={open}>
                                        <div id="example-collapse-text">
                                        <tr>
                                        <FilterGroup name="Yıllık Satış Artışı">
                                            <tr><FilterButton val1="0" val2="0.1"> %10'a Kadar Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                            <tr><FilterButton val1="0.1" val2="0.3">%10-%30 Arası Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                            <tr><FilterButton val1="0.3" val2=""> %30'dan Büyük Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                        </FilterGroup>
                                    </tr>
                                        </div>
                                    </Collapse>
```

**This is button 2**

```
<Button
                                        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                                        aria-controls="example-collapse-text_1"
                                        aria-expanded={open}
                                    >
                                        Satış Artışı
                                    </Button>

                                    <Collapse in={open}>
                                        <div id="example-collapse-text_1">
                                            <tr>
                                                <FilterGroup name="Çeyreklik Satış Artışı">
                                                    <tr><FilterButton val1="0" val2="0.1"> %10'a Kadar Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                                    <tr><FilterButton val1="0.1" val2="0.3">%10-%30 Arası Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                                    <tr><FilterButton val1="0.3" val2="">%30'dan Büyük Olanlar</FilterButton></tr>
                                                </FilterGroup>
                                            </tr>
                                    </div>
                                    </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you're using the same state for two button.
So you need two have 2 state but it's not the good solution

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState({
   button1: false, 
   button2: false
});
```

...

```
// button 1
<button onClick={() => setOpen({...open, button1: !open.button1)}>
<Collapse in={open.button1}>

// button 2
<button onClick={() => setOpen({...open, button2: !open.button2)}>
<Collapse in={open.button2}>
```

But it's really not the good solution too

I'm not sure Accordion need to be a list
But i'm sur you can do what you want with accordion

Keed safe !

Answer (score 0):

Use `Accordion` and `useAccordionToggle` hook like in [doc](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#custom-toggle-with-expansion-awareness)

Comment: But it is not a list. It placed in different fields.